# Stuck on not showing text with GET

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an user photo delete script that users can delete their own photo's.
The problem is that i want the user to confirm, so i did it with $_GET in my script. I wan't when the user press Delete, that the sentence "Do you really want to blabla" is only on the screen. And now it just goes after the delete button and image.

Script:

```
if(($_GET['delete'] == '') || ($_GET['yes'] == '')) {
    if($numrows != 0){
        foreach ($result as $row) {

             echo '
                        <div class="imgwrapklein">
                                        '.$row['caption'].'<br />
                                        <a href="show.php?photo='.$row['id'].'" title="'.$row['caption'].'"><img src="'.$row['location'].'" alt="'.$row['beschrijving'].'" /></a><br />
                                        <a href="?delete='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>
                                    </div>
                ';
        }   
    }else{
        echo 'There are no pics!';
    }
}else{
    echo 'Something went wrong!';
}

if($_GET['delete'] != ''){
    echo 'Are you sure you want to delete the picture <a href="?yes='.$_GET['delete'].'">Yes</a> - <a href="user-photo.php">No</a>';
}

if($_GET['yes'] != ''){
    // hier komt het verwijder gedeelte
}
```

Comment: why don't just use JavaScript to show the confirmation dialog?

Comment: @agree with tborychowski
JavaScript is more simple

Comment: if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the picture?")){
    //do something
}

Comment: You can use JavaScript whenever it comes to improving the user friendliness of your application. It should not be a prerequisite for running your site properly, despite rare users disabling it or having an older browser that doesn't support the commands you have used.

Comment: Oke i'll look into javascript, BUT is there a solution still for my question, so i can do something else with it?

Comment: don't use GET for delete.... or else you may end up having no files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried some more stuff, found this way with php:

```
if( isset($_GET['delete']) && ( $_GET['delete'] != '') ){
    echo 'Are you sure you want to delete the picture <a href="?yes='.$_GET['delete'].'">Yes</a> - <a href="user-photo.php">No</a>';
}else if( isset($_GET['yes']) && ( $_GET['yes'] != '' ) ){
    // hier komt het verwijder gedeelte
}else{
    if($numrows != 0){
        foreach ($result as $row) {

             echo '
                        <div class="imgwrapklein">
                                        '.$row['caption'].'<br />
                                        <a href="show.php?photo='.$row['id'].'" title="'.$row['caption'].'"><img src="'.$row['location'].'" alt="'.$row['beschrijving'].'" /></a><br />
                                        <a href="?delete='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>
                                    </div>
                ';
        }   
    }else{
        echo 'There are no images!';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

null is not equal to '' as far as i know...

so try

```
if( isset($_GET['delete']) && ( $_GET['delete'] != '') ){
    echo 'Are you sure you want to delete the picture <a href="?yes='.$_GET['delete'].'">Yes</a> - <a href="user-photo.php">No</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the best way is to us Javascript confirm() to validate the action. like this (using jquery):

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    if (confirm('do you really want to delete photo?')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you prefer use PHP you'll have to make another form to confirm the fact the user want to delete the photo.